# Call logic after /patch/request in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data REST.
In case of one /patch/ request for one particular entity, I would do sth (in this case send an event with saved object).
As I do not have code of /patch/ method because of Spring Data REST, I tried to use @RepositoryEventHandler and @HandleAfterSave annotations

```
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class MyHandler {
  @HandleAfterSave
  public void handleAfterSave(MyObj obj){
   //Do some after patch logic
  }
 }
```

It works, but handleAfterSave is called everytime I save MyObj entity. I want to call my logic only after saving object via /path/ request. How can I achieve it? Maybe via aspects? However, because I do not have the GetPatch method in my project, I have no idea how to wrap it by aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the event handler bounded with `MyObj` class. So if you really want to make it in respect with `url/path` you can either create an handler based on the request path. There is also another work around which seems to be working(I've not tested it yet.).

Pass another variable to the method signature to get the url path, and execute operation based on this:
Here is an example:

```
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class MyHandler {
  @HandleAfterSave
  public void handleAfterSave(MyObj obj, HttpServletRequest request){
   
   String uri = request.getRequestURI();   
   if(uri.equals("expected uri")){
      //Do some after patch logic
   }
  }
 }
```

Let me know if this work.